# Having trouble removing HTTP header "Cache-control"

Tags: apache-2.4, http-headers, cloudflare

I'm trying to get my assets cached using Cloudflare
Cloudflare states here [that](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168266-What-do-the-various-CloudFlare-cache-responses-HIT-Expired-etc-mean-) "CloudFlare will not cache your site or static content if you have  no-cache and private headers coming from your server"

As you can see from my file response, `Cache-control: no-cache="set-cookie"` is coming through:
https://redbot.org/?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.shareasimage.com%2Fstatic%2Fapp%2Fimages%2Fads%2Fts.ad.png

I've tried removing it using `Header unset Cache-control`, but no luck

Has anyone run into this before?

Comment: Where did you put that config, and what's the rest of your relevant config?

Comment: I put it in the `htaccess` file

Comment: here's the rest of the access file: http://pastebin.com/zB57Uddp

Comment: So it's not in there now? And do you know where the current contents of the header are coming from now?  The fact that `Cache-control` isn't capitalized in the header that you're getting now tells me it's being set elsewhere in your config.

Comment: I removed it because it didn't seem to work. Here are before and after of the `htaccess` file having the unset command. Before: http://i.imgur.com/PdKFhKE.png After: http://i.imgur.com/SFj7r31.png

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you've run into a bug because you have two different capitalizations of `Cache-Control`:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=259200, no-cache="set-cookie"
Cache-control: no-cache="set-cookie"
```

HTTP headers are case-insensitive, but you've probably run into an oddball edge case where Apache stops looking when it finds a match to what you're trying to remove - so the first one, `Cache-Control`, gets removed, while `Cache-Control` doesn't.

Either find where in your config or code the `Cache-control` header is being set and have it fully capitalize to the normal `Cache-Control` (then a `Header unset Cache-Control` should nuke both values), or make Apache search for the matching case-insensitive name twice, which should hopefully work:

```
Header unset Cache-Control
Header unset Cache-control
```

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts Shane. I considered that and tried it, but it didn't work. I found the answer to the problem though (and realize I failed to include some auxiliary information about my set up). Going to answer it now

Answer (score 0):

I failed to mention that my server(s) are behind a load balancer on AWS
AWS ELB (what they call their load balancers) have a setting call `stickiness`
When you turn it on, they set a cookie to make sure visitors consistently get sent to the same server

This has the added side effect of adding the following header after your server fulfills the request:
Cache-control: no-cache="set-cookie"

I needed to turn off stickiness to prevent this header from being set

In retrospect, I should've outlined my setup more to help debug this
Thanks for your help Shane

Answer (score 0):

Are you using mod_session?

There's a bug about this:

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61161